# CakePHP - model or controller duties?

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp

i have a model of User entity, which relies on some extra data from rest service. In my project i developed a package for retrieving that extra data and put it into Vendors/Components folders. So i have a register method in my User controller which accepts form data that is to be followed by extra data from rest service.

My question is where should I call rest service functionality and therefore retrieve and append to User data - in controller or in model ? 
ps my guess is that User model had better deal with rest functionality, but working with components in model is a little but awkward in models in cakephp.

Comment: why is it a component in the first place? with cake >= 1.3 it is cleaner to work with libs imo. components are only there to support controllers with specific controller-related stuff. everything else should never be a component. you could also make it a behavior, probably.

Comment: tbh im new to cakephp,so probably i misunderstood the concept of component, probably should place it in libs dir - but isn't it dedicated to cakephp-core-only functionality ?

Comment: no, app/libs/ is for your own ones (or app/Lib/ for cak2 - you didnt mention your version yet)

Comment: it's 2.0 version, as you said - i decided to switch to incorporating through Lib  folderand import function

Answer (score -1):

The 1.3 documenation is not so good on using libs.
But the 2.0 one explains it pretty good:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html

app/Lib

```
Contains 1st party libraries that do not come from 3rd parties or external vendors. This allows you to separate your organization’s internal libraries from vendor libraries.
```

for 2.0 then:
App::uses('ClassName', 'Lib');

Comment: exactly :) i just have misunderstood the conception about vendors

Comment: vendors are fine for third party stuff ;) if you invent it yourself, you don't really need it, right.